# Is this spell/item interaction as infinite (and potentially deadly) as I think it is?

Tags: spells, magic-items, anima-beyond-fantasy

The 12th-level Path of Destruction spell, Sphere of Destruction, takes 30 Zeon to cast, for an effect that does 30 Base Damage (+5 per an Added Effect).

The Prometheum Exxet introduces an effect, Power Boost, which "increases the number of Zeon points powering the wielder's spells (the listed amount is added on to the total Zeon, without cost to the character)."

If I have an item with Power Boost 30 or 40 (which exists, and is oddly attainable in my party...), can I then 'infinitely' (subject to not fumbling my magic projection roll etc. etc.) cast Sphere of Destruction (or indeed, any number of other spells that have a cost of 40 or less)?

Furthermore, in the case of Sphere of Destruction specifically, is this as combat-effective as I think it is (especially with the 40 Zeon variant)?

The wording of the Power Boost bonus is replicated below.

> **Zeon +X:** The amount of Zeon added to the spell when the wielder casts it. For example, a spell that normally costs 50 Zeon points to cast would only cost the caster 30 points if used with an item with a +20 Zeon Boost.  This power does not work for High Magic or Divine Magic spells.

Answer (score 1):

So, this isnt quite the answer that you're looking for, but my group saw similar issue with power boost, as it seemed disproportionately powerful as written.

Our ruling was... You still need to accumulate the Zeon required to cast the spell. The artifact refunds it back to your pool afterwards, similar to the unlimited Zeon meta-magic in the Arcana Exxet.

The answer that you're looking for however, as written does indeed do what you think it does. I still think it may be mistranslated though.

Elaborating further... The reason why my party decided to handle it this way, is because there are other effects that work very similarly in the Arcana. The Arcana was written afterwards, and is intended as an Errata to the existing magic system for the most part. Additionally, in my personal experience, you're still capped by your action limits.

Even if you go with the cost reduced method it's not that crazy. A wizard with 10 DEX and 10 AGI still only fires 4 sphere's of destruction, each for 30 damage.

This is easily eclipsed by a dual wielding fighter archetype character, who could easily be swinging for quadruple that. Alternatively, a stilleto thrower can potentially dish out 4 stilleto's per turn with just 120 attack.

Comment: Also, rules say you can cast as many spells as you like in a single casting action...I think.

Comment: Yes, that does appear to be the case. It is mentioned in the base book that provided the Zeon you can cast as many as you would like. Given that knowledge it would not make sense for someone to theoretically repeat cast the same spell an unlimited number of times in a turn... Seems prudent that it should be only usable for a single spell per turn. Unfortunately, this is just speculation, because it isn't obvious.